# TFS 2017 Builds - Stop build from executing further

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, vnext

We are using the new style TFS builds (Build vNext) to run our build orchestration. I am looking for a way to stop our builds if certain preconditions are not met. However, I can't find a way to stop the currently executing build without adding a variable and adding conditional logic in rest of the tasks. Is there a better way of stopping currently executing build? We are using TFS 2017 Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an in-line PowerShell task in the build with whatever logic you want -- if the exit code is non-0, the build will fail. If the down-stream tasks have "continue on error" off, they won't run.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a better way of doing it. Not fail the build and skip the rest of the tasks. I can use the new conditional tasks feature but that again will iterate through all the tasks.